# Get Parametrs from Url to Yii2 model

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have issue with getting parameter from URL to my Yii2 Model.

URL  : https://example.com/?key=test&id=1234

My code is :

```
public function save()
    {
        $httpClient = new Client();
        $keyword = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('key');
        $data = [
            'civilite'     => $this->civility,
            'nom'          => $this->lastName,
            'prenom'       => $this->firstName,
            'telephone'    => $this->phoneNumber,
            'email'        => $this->emailAddress,
            'operateur'    => $this->operator,
            'tel_domicile' => $this->phone,
            'keyword' => $keyword,
        ];

        $preferences = explode(',', $this->preferences);
        $index = 0;
        foreach ($preferences as $preference) {
            $index++;
            $data['attente' . $index] = $preference;
        }

        LeadLogHelper::log($data);
        $rawResponse = $httpClient->createRequest()
            ->setMethod('POST')
            ->setUrl(\Yii::$app->params['leadWebserviceUrl'])
            ->setData($data)
            ->send();
        $response = json_decode($rawResponse->content);

        if (!$response->Statut) {
            Yii::error('An error occurred while saving the data using the webservice', __METHOD__);
            Yii::error($data, __METHOD__);
            Yii::error($response, __METHOD__);
        }
        return $response->Statut == 1 || $response->Message === 'La Fiche existe déjà.';

    }
```

The Save function work, but with a null value for $Keyword, please Help!!

Comment: is keyword declared in the rules for your model?

Comment: Hi Muhammad, No it's not declared in rules, they should be?

Comment: yes  it should be, otherwise it wont load the value

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam There is no `load()` call here, so `rules()` should not matter.

Comment: @rob006 you are damn right , i overlooked that there isnt and $model->load() call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depend on your query link like: `https://example.com/?key=test&id=1234`

At the time when you call `$model->save()` method, special for this particular model you can pass an additional parameter as `$key` like this:

**Method 1**

```
//action controller
//Your model
 $model->save(\Yii::$app->request->get('key'))
```

Here is the model:

```
public function save($key = '')
    {
        $httpClient = new Client();
        $data = [
            'civilite'     => $this->civility,
            'nom'          => $this->lastName,
            'prenom'       => $this->firstName,
            'telephone'    => $this->phoneNumber,
            'email'        => $this->emailAddress,
            'operateur'    => $this->operator,
            'tel_domicile' => $this->phone,
            'keyword' => $key, // Or use if statement to include this value or not
        ];
        ...
    }
```

But it is safe to use model properties like this:

**Method 2**

```
//define a property
class YOUR_MODEL extends Model {
    ...
    public $key;
    ...
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ...
            [['key'], 'safe'],
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you can use this in controller:

```
$model->key = \Yii::$app->request->get('key');
```

In your model make changes:

```
public function save()
    {
        $httpClient = new Client();
        $data = [
            'civilite'     => $this->civility,
            'nom'          => $this->lastName,
            'prenom'       => $this->firstName,
            'telephone'    => $this->phoneNumber,
            'email'        => $this->emailAddress,
            'operateur'    => $this->operator,
            'tel_domicile' => $this->phone,
            'keyword' => $this->key
        ];

        ...
    }
```

And after that call `$model->save()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: They take always null value, with 2 methods, i don't know why??!!

Comment: @Belicoff Check that you  have get parameter assigned and in the model->save() make 1-st line to check if you get desired parameter in the model.

Comment: this is my controller $isSuccessfullySaved = $leadModel->save(Yii::$app->request->get('keyword'));

        if (!$isSuccessfullySaved) {
            $response = $this->asJson(['errors' => ['webservice' => 'Error while saving the lead']]);
            $response->statusCode = 550;
            return $response->send();
        }

Comment: My Model -->  public function save($keyword)
    {
        $httpClient = new Client();
        $data = [
            'operateur'    => $this->operator,
            'tel_domicile' => $this->phone,
            'keyword' => $keyword,
        ];
    }

Comment: But the link you have `https://example.com/?key=test&id=1234` which mean you have to pass the `\Yii::$app->request->get('key')`, but you pass `$leadModel->save(Yii::$app->request->get('keyword'));` <-- which may not even exist.

Comment: Yes sorry i have changed the parameter in the url from key to keyword => here is my model & controller https://gofile.io/d/zeXz9m

Comment: In controller behaviors you accept only `post` requests for this action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217263/discussion-between-belicoff-and-serghei-leonenco).